# Why the reverse order of "Zachor Veshamor" in "Lecha Dodi"?

Tags: tefilla, midrash, parashas-yisro, kabbalat-shabbat, mechilta

The first "stanza" in the *Lecha Dodi* hymn sung Friday night starts

> שמור וזכור בדיבור אחד

I gather that this expression is a "condensed version" from [Mechilta on Yitro](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42585&st=&pgnum=47) (parsha 7)

> זכור ושמור שניהם נאמרו בדיבור אהד

Why does *Lecha Dodi* have these in reverse order of the Midrash? I would also think that *Lecha Dodi* would follow the Torah's "chronological" order, i.e., *Yitro* appears first so *Zachor* should be mentioned first.

Comment: here's a variant that does have זכור ושמור in that order http://imhm.blogspot.com/2007/12/ezra-chwat-alternative-qabbalat-shabbat.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The beginning of each stanza spells the name of the author שלמה הלוי. I surmise that the author wanted to spell his name and therefore reversed the order.

Comment: You know ... I was so focused on composing my question after having written another related one on the Mechilta, that I completely overlooked this simple fact! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [Baruch She’amar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_Epstein) brings that while the remembrance occurs in the daytime (eve of shabbat) the observance takes place in the night (of shabbat), therefore the reversed order.